# How to lift and compose functions together?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash, ramda.js, lifting

I have a list of people in this structure:

```
const people = [
  {name: 'jenny', friends: ['jeff']},
  {name: 'frank', friends: ['jeff', 'ross']},
  {name: 'sarah', friends: []},
  {name: 'jeff', friends: ['jenny', 'frank']},
  {name: 'russ', friends: []},
  {name: 'calvin', friends: []},
  {name: 'ross', friends: ['frank']},
];
```

I would like to filter out people two ways: with and without friends; moreover I would like the [Predicate](https://github.com/hemanth/functional-programming-jargon#predicate) of the `Array.filter` to be [lifted](https://github.com/hemanth/functional-programming-jargon#lift), like so:

```
const peopleWithoutFriends = people.filter(withoutFriends);
console.log(peopleWithoutFriends);

const peopleWithFriends = people.filter(withFriends);
console.log(peopleWithFriends);
```

I can achieve this behavior by explicitly writing a `by` function like this:

```
const by = x => i => {
  return Boolean(get(i, x));
};
const withFriends = by('friends.length');
const peopleWithFriends = people.filter(withFriends);
console.log(peopleWithFriends);
```

**Problem:** If I wanted the inverse I would need to explicitly write a whole new function for `peopleWithoutFriends`

```
const notBy = x => i => {
  return !Boolean(get(i, x));
};

const withOutFriends = notBy('friends.length');
const peopleWithoutFriends = people.filter(withOutFriends);
```

*I do not want to write my `by` function twice.  I would rather compose smaller functions together.*

### **Question:**

**How can I write and use small functions like: [`flow`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#flow) [`Boolean`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean)[`get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get) [`curry`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#curry) [`not`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#not) and compose `withFriends` and `withOutFriends` Predicates for my Array.filter over the list of `people`.**

Repl: https://repl.it/@matthewharwood/ChiefWelloffPaintprogram

```
const {flow, get, curry} = require('lodash');

const people = [
  {name: 'jenny', friends: ['jeff']},
  {name: 'frank', friends: ['jeff', 'ross']},
  {name: 'sarah', friends: []},
  {name: 'jeff', friends: ['jenny', 'frank']},
  {name: 'russ', friends: []},
  {name: 'calvin', friends: []},
  {name: 'ross', friends: ['frank']},
];
const not = i => !i;

const withFriends = i => flow(
  Boolean,
  get(i, 'friends.length'), // arity of this is 2 so might be harder to lift, is it possible tho with curry?
); // No idea what i'm doing here.


const peopleWithFriends = people.filter(withFriends);
console.log(peopleWithFriends);

const withoutFriends = flow(not, withFriends);
const peopleWithoutFriends = people.filter(withoutFriends);
console.log(peopleWithoutFriends);
```

Comment: you are probably interested in `lodash/fp` as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the result of with/without friends functions is a Boolean, you can negate (or complement) the result of the one to get the other. In addition the arity of the functions is 1 (the object they operate on).

Lodash/fp:

```js
const { flow, get, isEmpty, negate } = _;

const people = [
  {name: 'jenny', friends: ['jeff']},
  {name: 'frank', friends: ['jeff', 'ross']},
  {name: 'sarah', friends: []},
  {name: 'jeff', friends: ['jenny', 'frank']},
  {name: 'russ', friends: []},
  {name: 'calvin', friends: []},
  {name: 'ross', friends: ['frank']},
];

const withoutFriends = flow(get('friends'), isEmpty); // create a function that gets the friends array, and check if it is empty
const withFriends = negate(withoutFriends); // negate the result of withoutFriends

const peopleWithFriends = people.filter(withFriends);
console.log(peopleWithFriends);

const peopleWithoutFriends = people.filter(withoutFriends);
console.log(peopleWithoutFriends);
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Ramda:

```js
const { pipe, prop, isEmpty, complement } = R;

const people = [
  {name: 'jenny', friends: ['jeff']},
  {name: 'frank', friends: ['jeff', 'ross']},
  {name: 'sarah', friends: []},
  {name: 'jeff', friends: ['jenny', 'frank']},
  {name: 'russ', friends: []},
  {name: 'calvin', friends: []},
  {name: 'ross', friends: ['frank']},
];

const withoutFriends = pipe(prop('friends'), isEmpty); // create a function that gets the friends array, and check if it is empty
const withFriends = complement(withoutFriends); // negate the result of withoutFriends

const peopleWithFriends = people.filter(withFriends);
console.log(peopleWithFriends);

const peopleWithoutFriends = people.filter(withoutFriends);
console.log(peopleWithoutFriends);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Notes:

1. Both `_.flow()` and `R.pipe` execute the sequence from left to right (top to bottom). The functions `_.compose()` and `R.compose` order is reversed.
2. The 1st function in flow/pipe/compose gets everything that is passed to the composed function. The other functions in the sequence always get a single param (the result of the previous function)/.
3. Both Ramda and Lodash have a reject method, which is the opposite of filter, if the predicate returns `true`, the item is removed. For example, `R.reject(foo, xs)` is equivalent to `R.filter(R.complement(foo), xs)`. (noted by @ScottSauyet's in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1243641/scott-sauyet))

Comment: In functional programming sometimes the terms are more confusing than the actual application :)

Comment: *"Both `flow` and `pipe` execute the sequence from right to left..."* - I think you mean *"left-to-right"*.

Comment: @user633183 - indeed :) Fixed.

Comment: Also note that Ramda's `reject` could be useful here.  `R.reject(foo, xs)` is equivalent to `R.filter(R.complement(foo), xs)`.